CVE-2024-32002 - ADO vulnerability?
My organisation have an instance of Azure DevOps Services. I have noticed recently that this vulnerability was opened on GIT:
https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2024-32002
I am wondering if this vulnerability impacts the version of GIT used within Azure DevOps Services or how I would find out what version of GIT is used with Azure DevOps services?
Thanks in advance
I have tried searching for an answer using a search engine but could not find anything decisive on the version used.

Are you using Microsoft-hosted or Self-hosted agents?

Did any of the below answers solved your problem?


how I would find out what version of GIT is used with Azure DevOps services?

You can check the logs of the checkout task to see which git version is being used.
Regarding the vulnerability, and according to the link you posted:

... problem has been patched in versions 2.45.1, 2.44.1, 2.43.4, 2.42.2, 2.41.1, 2.40.2, and 2.39.4

I just ran a pipeline using a Microsoft-hosted agent, and can confirm it is using a patched version:

As per Self-hosted agents, you need to update Git to an patched version.

For Microsoft-hosted agent, you can check the Git version from the Included Software list.  Check this to find the link of Included Software list for different agent Images.

For example, the current git version on windows-2022 and ubuntu-22.04 is Git 2.45.1.


